# Merge PHP arrays to create named keys and unique values

Tags: php, array-merge, array-unique

I have an object which contains 3 arrays, any of which *may* be empty, it is feasible all three can be empty, so I need to handle that requirement too.

Here's an example of the object:

```
{
    "lang_read": [],
    "lang_write": ["es", "ca", "zh", "en", "de", "he", "it", "ar", "ko", "pt", "ru"],
    "lang_listen": ["es", "ca", "en", "fr"]
}
```

I need to merge these 3 arrays into a single array with unique values, using the existing keys so that the output contains a reference to which array the merged array came from. Furthermore, the output must *prefer* the arrays in the order `lang_listen`, `lang_read` then `lang_write`.

Output should allow these to be listed in a HTML select list, so that the end user only selects one option.

I tried to do this, and managed to merge the arrays for unique values, but am stuck with the ordering requirement, and the keys requirement to reference which array the value originally came from with the following:

```
$mergedLanguages = array_unique(array_merge($languages->lang_listen, $languages->lang_read, $languages->lang_write), SORT_REGULAR);
```

However, this just produced a new array with numerical keys, and I have no way of referencing which array the value came from originally.

As an example of the desired output, which may be totally incorrect:

```
{
    "languages": [
        "lang_listen" => array("es", "ca", "en", "fr"), 
        "lang_write" => array("zh", "de", "he", "it", "ar", "ko", "pt", "ru")
    ]
}
```

Then I found need to build an HTML select list from this, something like:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($languages as $namedIndex => $arrayValues) {
   foreach ($arrayValues as $value) {
      echo '<option value="'.$value.'" data-type="'.$namedIndex.'">'.$value.'</option>';
   }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Because the order of priority is `lang_listen`>`lang_read`>`lang_write`, as `"es", "ca", "en"` exist in both `lang_read` and `lang_listen`, it these should only exist in `lang_listen` as it has priority over `lang_read`.

Can anyone advise what is the best approach and how to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: An example of the output you want would be really useful here, specifically how you want to identify which original array data came from

Comment: _"...the keys requirement to reference which array the value originally came from."_ is the part that puzzles me the most. An example would truly benefit you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not entirely certain to be honest. I have prototyped this in HTML and have built a select list which uses data attributes with the key name (e.g. `<option value="en" data-type="lang_write">en</option>`) so need to build an array which will be suitable for generating this output. What can you suggest for that, if anything?

Comment: It would still be useful to see which data you believe should reach the final array (from the example you give) You do realise that the KEYS you mention of these arrays are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and 0,1,2,3

Comment: @El_Vanja  I have added an example, and my desired output. I am not entirely certain the desired output is actually desired, or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input arrays have numeric keys [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will renumber the output array.

To avoid that you can use simple [`+` operation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) over arrays:

If a key exists in the left operand array, then it will not be added from the right operand.

```
<?php
$lang_read = [];
$lang_write = ["es", "ca", "zh", "en", "de", "he", "it", "ar", "ko", "pt", "ru"];
$lang_listen = ["es", "ca", "en", "fr"];

$result = $lang_listen + $lang_read  + $lang_write;

print_r($result);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => es
    [1] => ca
    [2] => en
    [3] => fr
    [4] => de
    [5] => he
    [6] => it
    [7] => ar
    [8] => ko
    [9] => pt
    [10] => ru
)
*/
```

But it still gives you no information about where the items came from. To get that information you can rearrange your arrays, so the language codes will be in keys, while values will store the source.

You can use [array_fill_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to do that.

```
<?php
$lang_read = ["he", "en"];
$lang_write = ["es", "ca", "zh", "en", "de", "he", "it", "ar", "ko", "pt", "ru"];
$lang_listen = ["es", "ca", "en", "fr"];

$result = array_fill_keys($lang_listen, 'listen')
        + array_fill_keys($lang_read, 'read')
        + array_fill_keys($lang_write, 'write');

print_r($result);

/*

Array
(
    [es] => listen
    [ca] => listen
    [en] => listen
    [fr] => listen
    [he] => read
    [zh] => write
    [de] => write
    [it] => write
    [ar] => write
    [ko] => write
    [pt] => write
    [ru] => write
)
*/
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to achieve. Now I can just do a `foreach $result as $lang => $type` to achieve my desired select list. Many thanks for your insights!